# operator & overload and indexing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Is it possible to create an "address of" (&) operator overload that would allow passing an arg? So kind of a mixture between overloading the operator [] and operator &.

So regular [] overload can be used like this

```
val = myobj[arg];
```

where:

```
SomeReturnType MyClass::operator[](SomeArgType i)
{
   // Code to handle indexing
}
```

But if we want a pointer to that item, what I'm looking for would provide this use:

```
ptr = &myobj[arg];
```

Maybe this isn't possible directly, and I know there's other ways to achieve this, but if it is possible I do not know the syntax.

Comment: Do you have a reason to overload `&`?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  Can you detail a little more why you want to do this?

Comment: If you make it `SomeReturnType& MyClass::operator[](SomeArgType i)` you will get a pointer to the indexed element with `ptr = &myobj[arg];` without overloading the address-of operator.

Comment: `ptr = &myobj[arg];` will work fine if `operator[]` returns by reference.

Comment: It depends on what `SomeReturnType ` is. You can code it to be a copy of the item, or a reference to it (which has some interesting features).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to overload adress of operator when `operator[]` returns a reference:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    int x;
    int& operator[](int){
        return x;
    }
};


int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cout << &f.x << "\n";
    std::cout << &f[42] << "\n";
}
```

[Possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/o8d9TYsn9):

```
0x7ffc8cd2d46c
0x7ffc8cd2d46c
```

The example uses only a single `int`, but it will be the same when `operator[]` is returning reference to an element of some container.

Returning a copy from `operator[]` and then get the adress of the original element is not possible via `operator&` overload (unless you return some proxy that holds both, the copy of the element and the adress of the original, from `operator[]`).